# Notify watch if iCloud accessibility status changes

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, reachability, watchos

My iOS app uses iCloud for synchronization among multiple iPhones where each iPhone may be linked with a watch.
Currently a watch communicates only with its iPhone using watch connectivity, i.e. only iOS connects directly with iCloud.

Among others, there are 2 important cases that influence the accessibility of iCloud: The network may be reachable or not (e.g. flight mode), and the iCloud account may be available or not (depending on the system settings).

If the status changes, iOS provides appropriate notifications (`ReachabilityChangedNotification`, `CKAccountChanged`).

**The problem:**

As far as I know, newer watches can connect to iCloud independently of the iPhone by WLAN or a phone network. But how can watchOS be notified of a iCloud accessibility status change, if the paired iPhone cannot communicate with the watch, e.g. because it is too far apart?
Of course, the network reachability of the watch might change any time, but a user at the remote iPhone could also enable/disable iCloud usage of the app.

Are there any comparable callbacks in watchOS?